# Konjunktiv 2 Passiv

Tags: subjunctive, passive

Hier gibt es 4 Aufgaben, die ich im Konjunktiv 2 schreiben sollte. Aber ich kann den Unterschied nicht verstehen zwischen Konjuntiv 2 Passiv Gegenwart und Konjunktiv 2 Futur. Kann jemand mir den Unterschied erklären, bitte?

> Passiv. Schreiben Sie die Sätze im Konjunktiv 2.
>
> 1. Wenn die Computer nicht dauernd abstürzen würden, ..(die E-Mails, schneller beantwortet werden)
> 2. Die Werbeanzeige ist viel zu klein. Wenn sie größer wäre, ..(sie, besser gesehen werden)
> 3. Wenn diese Artikel nicht so billig wären, ... (sie, nicht so viel verkauft werden)
> 4. Die App ist zu teuer. Wenn wir sie günstiger anbieten würden,..(sie, mehr gekauft werden)

Meine Antworten waren:

> 1. Wenn die Computer nicht dauernd abstürzen würden, würden die Emails schneller beantwortet.
> 2. Die Werbanzeige ist viel zu klein. Wenn sie größer wäre, würde sie besser gesehen.
> 3. Wenn diese Artikel nicht so billig wären, würden sie nicht so viel verkauft.
> 4. Die App ist zu teuer. Wenn wir sie günstiger anbieten würden, würde si mehr gekauft.

Aber in Lösungen steht:

> 1. Wenn die Computer nicht dauernd abstürzen würden, würden die Emails schneller beantwortet **werden**.
> 2. Die Werbanzeige ist viel zu klein. Wenn sie größer wäre, würde sie besser gesehen **werden**.
> 3. Wenn diese Artikel nicht so billig wären, würden sie nicht so viel verkauft.
> 4. Die App ist zu teuer. Wenn wir sie günstiger anbieten würden, würde sie mehr gekauft.

Warum ist es so? Warum haben sie da Futur benutzt anstatt nur Gegenwart? Wie kann ich sie unterscheiden? Oder ist es wirklich Futurform? Habe ich irgendwas falsch verstanden?

Comment: Bitte noch mal prüfen: Sollte nicht in allen vier Lösungen **werden** am Ende stehen?

Comment: Auf den ersten Blick scheint es mir, als sei der Konjunktiv nebensächlich. Im Deutschen wird in der Bedeutung des Futurs oft Präsenz gebraucht. Daran hat sich der OP begreiflicherweise gewöhnt. Trotzdem kann es zur Verdeutlichung (oder um die Grammatik zu üben) anders gemacht werden.

Comment: guck mal hier: https://imgur.com/a/KrvMSqh

Comment: Ich habe dieselbe Frage, die Lösung statt zu helfen, verwirrt

Answer (score 2):

Es gibt theoretisch einen Unterschied zwischen Konjunktiv 2 Passiv Gegenwart (von der Bedeutung her Gegenwart, die aber mit dem [Präteritum](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Genera/Flexion.html) des Konjunktivs II „würde“ konstruiert wird) und Konjunktiv 2 passiv Futur. Der Satz

> Wenn die Werbeanzeige größer wäre, würde sie mehr gelesen werden.

bezieht sich unmissverständlich auf ein vermehrtes Lesen in der Zukunft. Dagegen ist der Satz:

> Wenn die Werbeanzeige größer wäre, würde sie mehr gelesen.

zunächst als Erklärung dafür aufzufassen, daß die Anzeigen momentan wenig gelesen wird.

**Aber** wir wissen, daß im Deutschen das Futur oft durch ein Präsens ersetzt wird. So sagt man zum Beispiel:

> Morgen gehe ich nicht zur Schule!

Besonders in komplizierten Sätzen mit Konjunktiv wird das meiner Erfahrung nach fast immer getan. Ich sehe das als natürliche Folge der Verwendung des Präsens im Sinne des Futurs. [Diese Seite](https://deutschegrammatik20.de/passiv/konjunktiv-passiv/) erklärt es aber damit, daß zuviele Hilfsverben schlecht klängen:

```
Passiv: Der Lehrer würde von dem Schüler gefragt (werden).

Die Form würde werden klingt durch das doppelte Hilfsverb unschön,
deshalb wird der Infinitiv von werden meist weglassen. Dann entspricht
die Form dem Konjunktiv II Passiv für die Gegenwart.                      .
```

Answer (score 0):

Also die Beispiele 3. und 4. sind kein gutes Deutsch. Sondern: ... verkauft werden bzw. ... gekauft werden. Dieses "werden" ist die Passivform, weil sich verkauft bzw. gekauft auf ein Objekt bezieht; also auf den Artikel oder die App. Das "werden" hat hier genau genommen nichts mit der Zeit Futur zu tun.

Trotzdem Futur II Konjunktiv II:
Wenn diese Artikel nicht so billig wären, würden sie nicht so viel verkauft worden sein.
Die App ist zu teuer. Wenn wir sie günstiger anbieten würden, würde sie mehr gekauft worden sein.

Stilistisch etwas seltsam, aber wohl korrekt.

Grüße Christian

Comment: Futur 2  & Konjunktiv 2 passt nicht zu Konjunktiv Präsens in den "Wenn"-Teilen. Daher hört sich das auch so gruslig an, weil die Zeitfolge nicht passt.